# Why Currency symbol displays value like � in grails

Tags: grails, gsp, symbols

```
class Currency {

    static constraints = {
       name blank:false
    }
    String name
    char symbol
}
```

**In gsp,**

```
<g:textField name="symbol" value="${currencyInstance?.symbol}" required="" />
```

Currency class having syambol as attribute. In create, it displays value like �. i dont know why it is coming? how to make that place is empty in create page. In edit i have to display the symbol?

Comment: What do you mean by encoding? please make clear.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're not using UTF-8 encoding to show, or transmit, your symbol.

Comment: How to use that?. Already my main.gsp (layout) having <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: how are you getting this symbol? what is introducing it to your code? Which encoding is it in there?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change the encoding in Tomcat, please, see the link  below:

http://blog.oio.de/2010/12/31/solving-tomcat-encoding-problems-in-utf-8-webapps/